# Deserialize to String or Object using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have an object that sometimes looks like this:

```
{
   "foo" : "bar",
   "fuzz" : "bla"
}
```

and sometimes looks like this:

```
{
   "foo" : { "value" : "bar", "baz": "asdf" },
   "fuzz" : { "thing" : "bla", "blip" : "asdf" }
}
```

these classes would look like:

```
public class Foo {
   String value;
   String baz;
}

public class Fuzz {
   String thing;
   String blip;
}
```

where the first cases are shorthand for the second ones.  I would like to always deserialize into the second case.

Further - this is a pretty common pattern in our code, so I would like to be able to do the serialization in a generic manner, as there are other classes similar to `Foo` above that have the same pattern of using String as a syntactic sugar for a more complex object.

I'd imagine the code to use it would look something like this

```
public class Thing { 
  @JsonProperty("fuzz")
  Fuzz fuzz;

  @JsonProperty("foo")
  Foo foo;
}
```

How do I write a custom deserializer (or some other module) that generically handles both cases?

Comment: In your first example, "foo" is a JsonNodeType.STRING. Into what field of the type "Foo" would you like this string value deserialized? "value" or "baz"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make it generic we need to be able to specify name which we would like to set in object for `JSON primitive`. Some flexibility gives annotation approach. Let's define simple annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@interface JsonPrimitiveName {
    String value();
}
```

Name means: in case primitive will appear in `JSON` use `value()` to get property name for given primitive. It binds `JSON primitive` with `POJO` field. Simple deserialiser which handles `JSON object` and `JSON primitive`:

```
class PrimitiveOrPojoJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private String primitiveName;
    private JavaType type;

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonDeserializer<Object> deserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(type);
        if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            return deserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        } else if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            BeanDeserializer beanDeserializer = (BeanDeserializer) deserializer;
            try {
                Object instance = beanDeserializer.getValueInstantiator().getDefaultCreator().call();
                SettableBeanProperty property = beanDeserializer.findProperty(primitiveName);
                property.deserializeAndSet(p, ctxt, instance);
                return instance;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw JsonMappingException.from(p, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) {
        JsonPrimitiveName annotation = property.getAnnotation(JsonPrimitiveName.class);

        PrimitiveOrPojoJsonDeserializer deserializer = new PrimitiveOrPojoJsonDeserializer();
        deserializer.primitiveName = annotation.value();
        deserializer.type = property.getType();

        return deserializer;
    }
}
```

Now we need to annotate `POJO` fields as below:

```
class Root {

    @JsonPrimitiveName("value")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PrimitiveOrPojoJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Foo foo;

    @JsonPrimitiveName("thing")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PrimitiveOrPojoJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Fuzz fuzz;

    // getters, setters
}
```

I assume that all classes are `POJO`-s and follow all rules - have `getters`, `setters` and default constructor. In case constructor does not exist you need to change this `beanDeserializer.getValueInstantiator().getDefaultCreator().call()` line somehow which fits your requirements.

Example app:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Root.class));
    }
}
```

Prints for shortened `JSON`:

```
Root{foo=Foo{value='bar', baz='null'}, fuzz=Fuzz{thing='bla', blip='null'}}
```

And for full `JSON` payload:

```
Root{foo=Foo{value='bar', baz='asdf'}, fuzz=Fuzz{thing='bla', blip='asdf'}}
```

Comment: This. Is. Amazing.

Comment: This is great!  In our case, we require constructors to take parameters and annotate those with `@JsonProperty` instead of using `getDefaultCreator`.  How could I use it in that circumstance?

Comment: @Doug, in that case you need to use `call` method with `Object[]`: `call(Object[] args)`. You need to provide all required parameters. Size of array must match constructor definition. If it is not the same for all types, you need to provide extra data to deserialiser from annotation. But to keep it simple I suggest to create `no-arg` constructor.