# How do I configure a custom error message when using @JsonFormat?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

I got a problem here where I can't accept wrong date formats.

For example:

If the api request receive a date "2019-14-10" I can't accept it.
Right now when I receive that, JsonFormat gives me 2020-02-10.

To solve this, I added the lenient=OptBoolean.FALSE as shown here:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone = "America/Vancouver", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
private Date effectiveDate;
```

The problem now is that when I call the api passing a wrong date (2019-14-10) I just get back a 400 Bad request response.

Is it possible to create a custom response to this validation?

For instance, can I return something like this:

```
{
  "code": {
    "value": 4,
    "name": "InvalidRequest"
  },
  "message": "{effectiveDate=Date is invalid. Please choose a valid date}"
}
```

Or at least the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Valid when creating objects with jackson without controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457754/valid-when-creating-objects-with-jackson-without-controller)

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be something handled by Jackson directly.  This is something that a higher order validation API would handle, like [bean validators](https://beanvalidation.org/).