# java/ jackson question, Need to parse a JSON to a list of type Employee (currently using jackson) using logic check

Tags: java, json, object, jackson

Trying to read in a Employee JSON and parse it to a list of type Employee but I need to check if the firstname and lastname contain only alpha and the dob is in format MM/DD/YYYY. If not then don't create the Employee object. I am currently using jackson and am able to parse the json and create the list of type Employee but I'm not sure how to implement the logic to check for alpha and the date format.
Below is my code:

Employee JSON

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "dob": "12/25/1999"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Bob",
        "lastname": "Adams",
        "dob": "04/12/1970"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "lastname": "Chan",
        "dob": "05/05/1955"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Jack",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "dob": "06/24/1967"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Ken",
        "lastname": "Green",
        "dob": "02/11/1978"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Jake",
        "lastname": "Peralta",
        "dob": "09/24/1989"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Kevin",
        "lastname": "Jones",
        "dob": "03/12/1992"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Bruce",
        "lastname": "Powers",
        "dob": "06/22/1994"
    }
]
```

Employee class

```
public class Employee {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String dob;
    
    public Employee() {
        
    }
    
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String dob) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [firstName=" + firstname + ", lastName=" + lastname + ", dob=" + dob + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Parsing json to employee list

```
    private List<Employee> readEmpolyeeJson() {

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(inputJsonLocation != null || !inputJsonLocation.trim().isEmpty()) { //json location is not empty
            //read json
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            
            try {
                empList = objectMapper.readValue(new File(inputJsonLocation), new TypeReference<List<Employee>>(){});
            } 
            catch (JsonParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            System.out.println("empList length: "+empList.size());
            
            for(int i=0; i<empList.size(); i++)
                System.out.println(empList.get(i).getFirstname()+", "+empList.get(i).getLastname()+", "+empList.get(i).getDob());                                   
        }       
        return empList;
    }
```

Comment: I think, you need to use a validator library. For example "hibernate validator" or "java bean validator". You can even specify regex for your fields.

Comment: Take a look at [@Valid when creating objects with jackson without controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457754/valid-when-creating-objects-with-jackson-without-controller/55461776#55461776) question.

Comment: thanks to all who answered. I ended up using simple json from googlecode