# Validate 2 Json Fields for Not Null at the same time

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have below JSON . At any point of time only one of the field "car" or "bike" can be null .Not both at the same time.How can I validate json using Jackson annotations.
All the fields in JSON are mandatory

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "car": "Toyota",
    "bike": "Honda"
}
```

My Java Pojo Objects

```
  public class Example
 {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public Integer age;

    @JsonProperty("car")
    public String car;

    @JsonProperty("bike")
    public String bike;
```

Comment: Take a look at [@Valid when creating objects with jackson without controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55457754/51591). You can implement a new validator which would check these two fields: [How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want, you can use **@NotBlank** from javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

```java
 public class Example
 {
    @NotBlank(message = "This field cannot be blank")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public Integer age;

    @JsonProperty("car")
    public String car;

    @JsonProperty("bike")
    public String bike;
}
```

You can also try @NotNull or @NotEmpty from same package. They have some differences, see what best fit on your case.